# Unexpected of decloration в AIDE

Tags: android, aide

Хотел добавить webView в xml, прописал код в манифесте, но показывает ошибку Unexpected of decloration.

[image: Вот сам код]

Comment: Пожалуйста, вставьте в вопрос код и ошибку в виде текста, а не изображения. Причины, почему это очень желательно: [**1**](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode), [**2**](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/).

Comment: Нельзя писать код вне методов -  можно только объявлять поля и присваивать им значения.

Answer (score 1):

1. Вы пишете код за пределами метода. Так нельзя.
2. Вы перенесли без изменений код из активити во фрагмент. Так нельзя.

   - У фрагмента нет метода getIntent - передавайте данные через setArguments
   - Во фрагменте нельзя искать разметку прямо в нём. Используйте `view` из onCreateView для этого